# How to handle duplicate field values with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA to save User object for my project.

I have email unique field in object so my model is like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(schema = "public", name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String email;
}
```

UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

    List<User> findAllByAddressesContaining(Address address);

    User findByEmailIgnoreCase(String email);

    List<User> findAllByRoles_id(int id);
}
```

When I am trying to save user object with email already existing in DB with `userRepository.save(user)`
It works, So it updates existing user object in DB.
I want to exception to be thrown in case of unique constraint violation instead of new object update so I will be able to send `409 CONFLICT` status from my spring MVC controller.
How can I achieve this in most efficient and "correct" way?

Comment: You validate at the controller level using one of the various validation mechanisms available in Spring MVC and return an appropriate error: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Did you solve this issue @vadym-roganin?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving directly,you can do one thing ! You can create custom method that takes emailId as parameter and returns an integer like ... public int getCountForEmailId(String emailId); In that you pass your native query or HQL or JPQ and check first whether there is any emaild id exist and you can return that and throw custom exception from controller if return count > 0. I hope it is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that in the object model this expression

```
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint (columnNames = "email")
```

is used does not mean at all that in the table the constraint for the column is really created.

*Documenttation:
 ... Use the @UniqueConstraint annotation to specify that a unique constraint is to be **included in the generated DDL** for a primary or secondary table. ...*

This does not mean that something will be checked in runtime.
Ensure that this column constraint really exists at the database table level.
I guess you use spring?
You need to use this property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none/create/update/validate <- select this
```

This will **create/update/check** the schema when the context starts.
validate - just compare your definition of an entity (@Entity) with what is described in the database schema (types, columns, constraints, etc.) and will give an error if for example there is no constraint added to the schema.

After you add a data constraint to this column, you will receive a constraint violation exception every time you receive it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @Column(unique = true) to the required column along with your constraints added to your @Table annotation.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(schema = "public", name ="user",uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
}
```